# How to stop live tiles flip in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

My app displays news data on live tiles using PeriodicTask. Within the app i have given the user an option to enable/disable live tile updates.

When the user selects 'disable' i want the app's tile to stop flipping. I have tried removing the existing PeriodicTask. This has stopped the live tile from updating its content. But the tile still flips and displays whatever was the last updated content.

I would like to stop the tile from flipping altogether. How can it be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you just update the tile on disable with [`IconicTileData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.iconictiledata(v=vs.105).aspx) matching the "front" content?

Comment: @Ithibodeaux: that option did cross my mind. But it would still not prevent the tile from flipping. I have noticed that the tile does not flip until we have updated its content for the first time. After that is there a way to stop it from flipping?

Answer (score 1):

First, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206971(v=vs.105).aspx for create FlipTileData with XML. 
    And the FlipTileData has got a constructor taking xml context as its parameter:FlipTileData(string xmlContent). 
    You want to stop it from flipping, you use Action="Clear" to clear up the back contents.

Following is my testing code.

```
        string xmlFlipTileData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\" Version=\"2.0\">";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:Tile Id=\"1\" Template=\"FlipTile\">";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:Count>5</wp:Count>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:Title>[title]</wp:Title>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:SmallBackgroundImage IsRelative=\"true\">Assets/Tiles/FlipTileSmall.png</wp:SmallBackgroundImage>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:BackgroundImage IsRelative=\"true\">Assets/Tiles/FlipTileMedium.png</wp:BackgroundImage>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:WideBackgroundImage IsRelative=\"true\">Assets/Tiles/FlipTileWide.png</wp:WideBackgroundImage>";

        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:BackTitle Action=\"Clear\"> </wp:BackTitle>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:BackContent Action=\"Clear\"></wp:BackContent>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:WideBackContent Action=\"Clear\"></wp:WideBackContent>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:BackBackgroundImage IsRelative=\"true\" Action=\"Clear\"></wp:BackBackgroundImage>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "<wp:WideBackBackgroundImage IsRelative=\"true\" Action=\"Clear\"></wp:WideBackBackgroundImage>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "</wp:Tile>";
        xmlFlipTileData += "</wp:Notification>";
        FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData(xmlFlipTileData);
        ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault();

        if (TileToFind != null)
        {
            TileToFind.Update(TileData);
        }
```

Hope this can do some help. -Jieke

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it's really easy to stop it from flipping. Just set all the back content to nothing, then everything is ok. Clear the back tile, back contents and back images.

-Jieke